# Reciept status 21000 when validating with https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt In App Purchase

Tags: ios, transactions, in-app-purchase

When I reach in SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased

i encode receipt as 
         [[NSString alloc] initWithData:transaction.transactionReceipt encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

but when i verify the receipt with https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt

the status is always 21000

I am Unable to get the reason

heres the receipt 
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

Can anyone help me

Comment: If you are working on iOS you don't need to base64 encode the transactionReceipt, it is already encoded; furthermore transactionReceipt is depracated, use appStoreReceipt instead

Answer (score 0):

Status codes for apple response are [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html)

In particular, you are getting

21000
The App Store could not read the JSON object you provided.

[Here](http://blog.goforyt.com/category/ios/) you'll find many interesting information on implementation details

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation, the code means that the json object you sent with the request has an issue. However I see that also if you send a get request instead of a post request, you would get the same code.

I would make sure the json object is valid and the request is post request.